Signal attenuated in the passband of scipy digital filter
I am trying to filter a signal using a high pass filter. The complete Python code for a minimal working example is below and link to all files here
The problem that I am facing is that the filtered signal is attenuated within the passband. I don't understand why this is and so I am seeking some explanation.
Two images are attached. One is generated from the code. The other is a zoomed in version of what is generated from the code.
If anyone could help me understand why I am getting this result, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!
output
output_zoom
I tried plotting like this to see if I could understand the situation better, but to no avail.
# %% modules
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %% load data
data = np.load("data.npz")
t = data['t'].squeeze()     # (s)       time vector
dt = np.diff(t)[0]          # (s)       sample period
fs = 1/dt                   # (Hz)      sampling rate
y = data['y'].squeeze()     # (null)    signal

# %% create filter and filter data
# define filter function
def highpass(data: np.ndarray, cutoff: float, sample_rate: float, poles: int = 5):
    sos = sc.signal.butter(poles, cutoff, 'highpass', fs=sample_rate, output='sos')
    filtered_data = sc.signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, data)
    return filtered_data, sos

# filter the data
cutoff = 0.1                                    # (Hz)      cutoff frequency
poles  = 100                                    # (null)    filter order
yF, sosfilt = highpass(y, cutoff, fs, poles)

# %% compute power spectrum
fout1,psd  = sc.signal.welch(y.squeeze(),fs)
fout2,psdF = sc.signal.welch(yF.squeeze(),fs)

# %% plot
fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,1)
fig.tight_layout()

# time domain
axh = ax[0]
axh.plot(t, y)
axh.set(xlabel='Time (s)',
          ylabel='Amplitude')
axh.grid()

# filter characteristics
axh = ax[1]
w, h = sc.signal.sosfreqz(sosfilt, worN=8000,fs=fs)
db = 20 * np.log10(abs(h))
yUB = np.max(db[np.isfinite(db)])
yLB = np.min(db[np.isfinite(db)])
axh.plot(w, db)
axh.fill_betweenx([yLB,yUB],cutoff,fout1[-1],
                    color='g',
                    alpha=0.1)
axh.set(xlabel='Frequency (Hz)',
        ylabel='Filter Freq. Response (db)')
axh.grid()

# power spectrum
axh = ax[2]
yUB = np.max(np.fmax(psd,psdF))
yLB = np.min(np.fmin(psd,psdF))
axh.plot(fout1, psd)
axh.plot(fout2, psdF)
axh.fill_betweenx([yLB,yUB],cutoff,fout1[-1],
                    color='g',
                    alpha=0.1)
axh.set_yscale('log')
axh.set(xlabel='Frequency (Hz)',
          ylabel='Power spectrum')
axh.legend(["Original","Original Filt.","Passband"],loc="lower right")
axh.grid()

plt.savefig("output.png",format="png")
plt.show()


Welcome to SO. We miss a link to the data file to make the exemple complete. Cheers.

You can find the complete code here

Filter passbands don't have razor-sharp edges. Most often, the cut-off frequency is defined as the point where attenuation is 3db, or about half power.
Generally, the steepness of the passband edge increases with filter order.
If you want to get rid of the highlighted attenuation, you can just move the cutoff frequency down by 0.05.  Increasing the order would mean you have to move it less, but that also increases delay.

I'd say half power, or about 3 dB ;)

So my idea of the passband is wrong, right? Is what you described related to the rolloff?
